# Retrieve all records of model (ORM2, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, node-orm2

Using the ORM2 module in Node.js, after creating a connection and checking that works, I can't find a way to retrieve all the records of a model, like the ActiveRecord's way Model.all . I'm new to ORM2 and it seems pretty obvious, but I don't have a clue...

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it:

```
var Blah = db.models.blah;
Blah.all(function(err, blahs){


})
```

Looking at the code Model.js which defines the methods for the Model (Blah above) has the following line:

```
model.all = model.find;
```

So I assume Blah.find() would work as well.  The methods used in the model instances are defined in the file Instance.js.  The documentation isn't super, but I have been happy with the project so far, and likely can help out if you have questions

Comment: Exactly, that was it! I come from Rails (ActiveRecord) and I really like this module (though it's necessary to change to the async mental modus) but I couldn't figure out this...

Comment: you should consider using promises via a library like Q, it makes the library a bit easier.